# Git ignore file not working under windows 10

Tags: git

I have these as the contents of my .gitignore file in my repo directory:

```
.history
.vs
sh.exe.stackdump
```

The .gitignore file is saved. Yet when I do a git status, I'm still seeing files in the .history and in the .vs directory:

```
    modified:   .vs/ProjectSettings.json
    modified:   .vs/VSWorkspaceState.json
    modified:   .vs/aws_scripts/v15/.suo
    modified:   .vs/slnx.sqlite
    new file: 
.history/python/virtualenvs3/boto3/aws_ec2_terminate_instances_20190313130950.py
            new file:   .history/python/virtualenvs3/boto3/aws_ec2_terminate_instances_20190313143848.py
            new file:   .history/python/virtualenvs3/boto3/aws_ec2_terminate_instances_20190313143932.py
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I exclude these directories?

Answer (score 2):

.gitignore *doesn't* work for files that are already tracked.

Comment: To untrack a file, you can use `git rm --cached <file>`

Comment: @Ferrybig it's just not that simple. You can remove the file going forward.... but then you do: `git checkout HEAD~1; git checkout my-branch` and then the file is gone from the working tree... and you start to wonder why that happened in the first place.